# CoreData Delete Rules | Cascade + Deny?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am wondering if I made the right choices setting my CoreData delete rules.

Suppose we look at a department with n employees.

I want to delete the department, **if and only if** there are no employees left.
So the other way holds as well. When all employees of the department are gone, the department should be deleted.

Is it correct to use cascade for the `department` relationship and deny for the `employees`?

Say, what happens when I set cascade to the `department` relationship but it has an inverse relationship `employees` which is set to deny?

#### Visualizated

Department <---->> Employee

**Cascade**: Department <---- Employee

**Deny**:    Department -->> Employee

Thank you!

Comment: For Department <-------- Employee I would rather have nullify than cascade, You cant delete the employee just because the department is deleted. rather I would have an employee with department value nullified. Where as Department ------->> Employee set to Deny makes sense, delete department when no employee is associated with it. I am assuming employee without department is allowed in your usecase

Comment: Thanks for you help! But now the department wont get deleted after every employee is gone?

Comment: It will, you still have Department ----->> Employee set as Deny correct? So once you delete all employees in that department, department will be deleted. Where as when you delete a department you will have number of employees with nil as department value

Comment: Ahh okay awesome! One last question: If I delete a department, doesn't the deny stop it from getting removed if there are still employees associated with it?

Comment: Good question, never tried this edge case :) you will have to experiment on it with a small set of data :)

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much for the help :)